# Make a vector out of slices of a large dataframe

Tags: r, gis

I have a large dataframe df whose elements are zipcodes and the associated shapefiles.

There is a territory field df$V2 with around 150 territories.

For each of these territories I am running gTouches to create the adjacency matrix for the associated zip codes.  What I want ultimately is a list with 2 fields - the Territory Name (a character) and the Adjacency Matrix (a matrix) - this matrix will be a square matrix but will not be the same size for every element.  This list will have 150 elements (1 per territory).

My code looks like this (and I apologize this is definitely embarrassing but I'm a novice):

```
Adjacency_Matrices<-list()
for(i in 1:length(unique(as.character(df@data$V2))))
{Adjacency_Matrices[[i]][1]<-unique(as.character(df@data$V2))[i] 
Adjacency_Matrices[[i]][2]<-
gTouches(df[df@data$V2==unique(as.character(df@data$V2))[i],], byid=TRUE)}
```

So line 1 is looping through the length of my list of unique territories.  Line 2 is defining the first field of the list (a string).  Line 3/4 defines the second field of the string (gTouches output is a square matrix).

I get two separate errors:

1) number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

2) Error in Adjacency_Matrices[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

I have googled 1 over and over and can't seem to find a way to fix this.  Number 2 I think is something I'm simply missing about how to instantiate lists in R.

Any help is appreciated and let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output so we can actually run and test the code. Explicitly list any packages/libraries you are using outside of base R.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was overthinking this.

You can't define Adjacency_Matrices[[i]][1] before you've defined i itself.

All I needed was rather than try to define Adjacency_Matrices[[i]][1] then Adjacency_Matrices[[i]][2] separately I just need to use list() to define my output list.

```
Adjacency_Matrices<-list(
for(i in 1:length(unique(as.character(df@data$V2))))
{Adjacency_Matrices[[i]]<-list(unique(as.character(df@data$V2))[i], 
gTouches(df[df@data$V2==unique(as.character(df@data$V2))[i],], byid=TRUE))}
```